# iPhone Development xcode : Putting user input (names) into text array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I am trying to load names in an array using UIAlert and then print them one by one. I am not able to figure this out, can anyone help me out with this? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", nil];

for (NSString *element in array) 
{
    // Log to console..
    NSLog(@"element: %@", element);

    //Show in alert.. Really?? 
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ALERT TITLE" message:element delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];
     [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",nil];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ALERT TITLE" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

for(NSInteger index=0; index<[array count]; index++)
{
 [alert addButtonWithTitle:[array objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```